# How to enable 4GB in my Windows 7 64 bit?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, memory, bios

I have the following machine configuration:

- Intel Core 2 Duo E6300
- 1 x 2048 MBytes memory chip
- 2 x 1024 MBytes memory chip
- 1 x Radeon HD 4870
- Motherboard : Gigabyte 945P-S3
- Windows 7 RTM 64-bit

In both Windows and the BIOS I have 3.25GB memory available. How can I enable it to support 4GB?

EDIT: I've *sort of* upgraded the CMOS version, and Windows acknowledges I have 4GB but is only using 3.25GB.

[image]

I guess it is hardware after all?

Comment: I'm fighting the [same battle](http://www.solo-technology.com/blog/2009/09/02/64-bit-isnt-always-the-answer/) right now. Pretty sure we're hosed with the i945 chipset. Granted, I'd *love* to be proven wrong!

Answer (score 16):

Your BIOS needs to support memory hole remapping.

Memory hole is there since all devices must fit in 32-bit address space during boot (since BIOS is not aware whether you will use 32-bit or 64-bit OS later). Remapping takes care to move affected memory to memory area after 32-bit boundary.

I would check whether new BIOS firmware is available if that setting is not in your current BIOS firmware.

Comment: Yes, there is a newer firmware version. Right now I've F2 installed. I will try to update, right? bit.ly/M0Fgv

Comment: @ArielBH: yes, update is almost always a good thing.

Comment: Strangest thing. I tried to update the CMOS. I did every step by the book. The cmos failed to load. I had to clear the CMOS. CMOS is up again, and now when I check the version, it indicate the new version, how can it be?

Comment: @ArielBH: It is definitely strange. I would try to update it once more just to check whether it updated everything. Most BIOS update routines check whether old BIOS fits ok.

Comment: @josip frankly I feel lucky that I've managed to get the cmos to work again. I think I will not touch it anymore :)

Answer (score 4):

[Josip](https://superuser.com/users/4732/josip-medved) is correct that the BIOS with memory hole remapping is necessary.  As [Chris_K](https://superuser.com/users/1540/chrisk) tries to say your hardware must also to be able to physically address more than 4GB see [KB929605](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929605).  I believe that the Intel 945 chipset family cannot do this.  So, sorry to say you are out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 x64 should recognize that RAM with no fiddling required.

If the BIOS doesn't recognize all 4 GB, there's no chance Windows will see it.  It's possible that the reason they provide a [memory support list](http://www.gigabyte.us/FileList/MemorySupport/motherboard_memory_ga-945p-s3.pdf) is because the board is very choosy.

I would each of your ram sticks individually, to make sure the BIOS sees them correctly.

Now that I'm thinking about it, the SU guys are going to have a lot more experience with this.

Comment: Josip is probably right - did you find any options related to memory hole remapping in the bios?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the 945 chip set doesn't support more than 4 GB of address space (and some versions only 2GB).  So you end up with the same limitation as Vista 32 bit - you won't be able to use all of 4 GB of your RAM since address space is used for more than just RAM.

From the [Intel 945 chip set datasheet](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/datasheet/307502.pdf) page 24:

> The (G)MCH supports 32-bit host
>   addressing, decoding up to 4 GB (2 GB
>   for the 82945PL/82945GC/82945GZ) of
>   the processor’s usable memory address
>   space

And of page 205:

> Addressing of memory ranges larger
>   than 4 GB (2 GB for
>   82945GC/82945GZ/82945PL) is not
>   supported

Answer (score 0):

The manual for your motherboard doesn't say it is a requirement, but it does advise using the same size memory modules. It's possible that having 1gb modules being scanned first is preventing it from detecting the larger 2gb module.

I would try swapping which bank the modules are in ( 1x2gb <-> 2x1gb ) and see if that helps, failing that I think you just need to get two 1gb modules to replace your existing 2gb module.

Of course, the up-side of the latter would be that you'd re-enable dual-channel and get faster memory use of the system.

Comment: Yes, I had those 2*1GB chips. My last visit to Redmond, USA i've bought 2 chips of 2GB. As it happens one of them was faulty, so I got stuck with only one (and I live abroad USA).

Comment: Yeah--I would never mix memory chips like that.  It's not the culprit but it's just asking for trouble.