# Will it be effective installing 4GB of RAM instead of 3GB on Windows 7 32-bit?

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory

Will it be effective installing 4GB of RAM instead of 3GB in a Windows 7 32-bit system?

Will I feel any difference?

Comment: I asked a similar question last year: http://superuser.com/questions/40978/on-a-intel-core-duo-laptop-running-windows-7-32-bit-will-there-be-performance-is

There should be no performance hit, at the very least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's not that much extra cash, go for it. You'll get SOMETHING out of that extra GB (Likely .25gb-.5gb, though it depends massively on your other components), and you can install 64bit Win7 whenever if you ever need that extra bit.

Answer (score 3):

The bigger issue will be how many devices/expansion cards you have.  For example if you have on board video - that will subtract from your memory total.  Other addon cards or onboard audio and network will also take up small amounts of memory - which is why everyones experience and amount varies.
[Coding Horror Article - Where is my 4 gig of memory?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/dude-wheres-my-4-gigabytes-of-ram.html)  <-- Best article I have seen explaining this.

Answer (score 2):

Depends.  Your system may only address 3.5GB or so.  Whether it makes a difference will depend on the apps you are running. Also on how many apps at the same time.