# Leak of RAM in Windows 7 (available 767MB of 2GB)

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory-leaks

After system crash (Win 7) there are only 767 mb available of 2gb.
I had this problem several times, but system restore and several reboots helpes me, but now i don't know what to do. Any ideas? dxdiag, bios and windows said that "RAM: 2gb" but win7 said that only 767 availiable.

Comment: windows memory utility said that everything is fine, there was a error while waking up from Hibernate mode

Comment: main problem that "Reserved for device mempory: 1281mb" is there any way to fix this size ?

Comment: you don't by chance have an integrated video adapter that shares RAM with the system do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reaseon was "Hardware reservd operation memory" had 1280mb of 2gb there are some ways to solve this problem.
1)to change boot config "msconfig"
2)to enable\disable RAM mapping in bios
3)to restore system from archive

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a hardware problem in your memory. Run some sort of memtest http://www.memtest86.com/

Might be also the source of the crashes.

Answer (score 2):

Where do you see that only 767 MB are available?

If this is in Task Manager, beware of badly interpreting the numbers you see, as they includes the cache memory which is released when required.

See this article [What do the Task Manager memory columns mean?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/What-do-the-Task-Manager-memory-columns-mean).

If you suspect that one program is using too much memory, you might in the "Processes" tab want to choose in the View menu "Select columns" entry, to view the column `Memory - Working Set`. Click the column twice to sort the processes by descending order.