# Windows detects only 4.75GB of 8GB RAM

Tags: windows-7, memory, 64-bit

I have Windows 7 64 bits Home Premium with 2x4GB Ram, but the system shows only 4.75GB available in Windows.

Comment: So you're only seeing 4.75 GB of memory?

Comment: Just post a screenshot of the “Memory” tab in Resource Monitor to clarify the problem, before all the obvious questions will come again.

Comment: Please specify what you have already tried, provide a screenshot of your task manager and help us to fully understand your problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [8.00GB RAM (3.22GB usable) in Windows 7 x64](http://superuser.com/questions/372751/8-00gb-ram-3-22gb-usable-in-windows-7-x64), http://superuser.com/questions/405579/installed-memory-ram-8gb-4gb-useable?rq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/89997/windows-only-sees-768-mb-ram-out-of-4-gb?lq=1

Comment: While this may well be a duplicate, it certainly ain’t one of that question. ;)

Comment: and it doesn't matter if its a duplicate if the original has no accepted answer and the original op rejected all the answers offered as non-pertinent to her situation.

Comment: I had such an issue when I bought CoD:Ghosts it needed 8GB RAM so I bought some but it didnt detected it properly, it appeared my RAM wasnt properly plugged, even though I was sure it was properly done, you should try re-inserting your barrets...

Answer (score 4):

There are tons of questions like this on the internet as well as on this site such as [8.00GB RAM (3.22GB usable) in Windows 7 x64](https://superuser.com/q/372751/241386)

There are many possible reasons and you need to check each:

1. The most common problem is that *memory mapping is disabled*. You need to go to BIOS setup and look for memory remapping or something like that and enable it. If nothing is found, update BIOS to the latest version and recheck. If still no entry like that, try the next one.

   See [Installed Memory (RAM): 8GB (4GB Useable)](https://superuser.com/q/405579/241386)

   [image: memory remapping]
2. Go to BIOS setup and try reducing or disabling shared RAM for video card
3. <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> > type `msconfig` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. In tab `Boot` open `Advanced options` and check if `Maximum memory` is being checked. If true, uncheck it
4. Check if there are any devices taking addresses too much. Disable it or reinstall driver

   [Windows only sees 768 MB RAM out of 4 GB](https://superuser.com/a/90920/241386)
5. Take out the memory modules, swap them or plug them into the other pair of slots (if any). Clean the pins if necessary.

If all the other solutions don't work, you may have no luck.

You can read about the reasons and solutions on [MS support](https://web.archive.org/web/20150121050808/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978610) and [MS technet](https://web.archive.org/web/20140302234227/http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/07/21/3092070.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Create a boot disk using MemTest86+ and use it to diagnose your RAM. You can download an *.iso here:
http://www.memtest.org/

Or try booting with stick 1 and see if the system recognizes 4GB, then use stick 2 by itself and see if it recognizes 4GB. Then put one stick in slot 2 and none in slot 1 and see what it recognizes. You want to diagnose each stick and each slot to see if there's a hardware issue.