# 7.25GB usable memory out of 8GB

Tags: memory, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is usable RAM less than total RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/54056/why-is-usable-ram-less-than-total-ram)

I have a strange issue with my PC. Today, I noticed that Windows 7 is reporting only 7,25GB out of 8GB memory usable. The strange part is that when I bought the PC it showed 8GB of memory usable. What happened in the mean time with more then 700MB?

I've seen others complaining about similar issues but no definite answer.

Can someone help me? My PC is a Toshiba Satellite P775.

Comment: Wrong site. Also, the main cause for this usually is the built-in video adapter which "borrows" system memory to use as its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Vilx the computer must be setup to share 750MB of system RAM with the video card.  [This website](https://us.toshiba.com/computers/laptops/satellite/P770/P775-S7215/) shows that the shared memory can be set 64MB-1696MB.  If you use the program [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) you can see how much system RAM the video card is using.

[image]