# 64-bit Windows 7 can only use 3.25GB of RAM instead of 4GB?

Tags: windows-7, memory, dram

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable 4GB in my Windows 7 64 bit?](https://superuser.com/questions/35731/how-to-enable-4gb-in-my-windows-7-64-bit)

My Windows 7 is 64-bit, and I thought that means it can use the full 4GB of RAM installed on the computer.

But I just saw this on my computer's properties:
(So only 3.25GB is usable??)

[image]

Comment: Maybe you're experiencing the same issues as:
http://superuser.com/questions/35731/how-to-enable-4gb-in-my-windows-7-64-bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually down to either memory being shared against a graphics card or a motherboard limitation that prevents 4GB of memory being accessible.

Comment: Graphics card seems to be more often the case as far as I have seen

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked how much ram your video is sharing? Although with an experience score of 5.9 it's not too likely you are using on-board. Something to clarify in the details anyway.