# WIndows 7 64 bit reporting 3.00 gb usable memory with 4.00 gb installed

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable 4GB in my Windows 7 64 bit?](https://superuser.com/questions/35731/how-to-enable-4gb-in-my-windows-7-64-bit)

I have a computer that I have upgraded to Windows 7 Professional 64bit.  It has an intel D945GB1 motherboard, Pentium D Dual core processor, nVidia Quadro FX 580 video card, 4 sticks of DDR2 1 GB memory.  In the BIOS, I see all 4 sticks of memory.  The Resource Monitor shows 1027 MB "Hardware Reserved".

I would try to get with intel about the motherboard, but it was made for Gateway's Business division which is no longer around, so I have no resources to tap into there.  I cannot find if there was an update to the BIOS to fix the problem.  The computer was originally sold to me as an XP Pro machine (32 bit) with 2 GB memory.  The Upgrade Advisor indicated no problems like this.

When I remove the video card and run on the onboard video, the Hardware Reserved goes down to 780 MB or so.  When I disable the onboard video, it goes back to 1027.  In the memory table in device manager, I see from C0000000 to F0000000 (about 805 meg) used by PCI Bus in one block, but cannot find what on the bus is doing with this.  I cannot find memory remapping in the bios, the max memory in msconfig is UNchecked, I have upgraded what drivers I can find, I have tried everything I an think of.

Any ideas?

Comment: I know this is going to sound off - but are you sure you've installed the 64 bit version of Windows 7? Go to `Control Panel\System and Security\System` and see what it says.

Comment: Yes it is 64 bit.  I have seen things like that before, so no problem.

Answer (score 9):

The Intel 945 chipset only supports 32 bit memory address (yes even though it supports 64 bit CPU's).  It's the same effect as having a 32 bit OS, but this limit is imposed in hardware so there is no solution other than getting a new motherboard.

See [How to enable 4GB in my Windows 7 64 bit?](https://superuser.com/questions/35731/how-to-enable-4gb-in-my-windows-7-64-bit)

Comment: AHA!!!!!!!!!!  I knew that there would be a SOLID reason for this.  I have the same problem with TWO computers.  Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 4):

If you're sure you have 64-bit Windows 7, your issue is probably that the frontside bus chip is 32-bit only, so it won't let even a 64-bit OS on a 64-bit processor use all 4 gigs of RAM properly.

Comment: Would this cause any other issues? - i.e. would you recommend using 32bit OS? I'm having video playback issues http://superuser.com/questions/1010981/pc-ram-unusable-and-flatlining-as-is-cpu-movies-failing-to-play