# Can a 2GB DDR2 stick become a 1GB stick?

Tags: linux, memory, ddr2, ddr

I've just purchased a 2GB DDR2 RAM. My machine earlier had a 1GB DDR2 RAM stick. Now I put these two sticks together, and my machine, I think, showed only 2GR of RAM?

Why is this so? Will using the 2GB+1GB together corrupt the 2GB stick?

Update:

The computer has a linux based os installed. I did an lspci command and saved the paste online. It can be reached [here](http://pastebin.com/K60m72ku) - this can give you some information on the chipset being used, I hope.

I have obtained a 2gb DDR 2 stick, but when I install it on my pc and boot, at the BIOS, it says **983040 k OK + 64M** during memtest. When I did my math it comes to 1GB.

Comment: What Brand and Model is your motherboard. You should be able to google the specs and see what the maximum amount is.

Comment: Intel Pentium Core 2 Duo

Comment: What is the motherboard? Chipset? Look here: http://superuser.com/questions/35731/how-to-enable-4gb-in-my-windows-7-64-bit

Comment: updated question.

Comment: What's your exact motherboard model? If the BIOS reports 1GB, your motherboard probably couldn't accommodate more, or the new stick is incompatible or severely damaged. Under Linux, lspci is useless here, what you should show is the output of `free`, of `dmidecode`, and logs from the kernel boot (like [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15256)).

Answer (score 3):

- Check your motherboard manual. Some of the have special requirements regarding slot population (type/size/speed).
- Download CPU-Z (I'm assuming you're using windows) and check how it sees your Dimms

Comment: CPU-Z should be able to show which RAM stick is actually recognized by the system (which is probably the case).

Answer (score 2):

Your motherboard probably has a 2gb max.

Comment: would seem unlikely, particularly if its even remotely modern. May be the mobo has requirements about slot position or ordering (1 & 3, 2 &4 etc).,