# Windows 7 64-bit doesn't show all 4 GB memory as available

Tags: windows-7, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable 4GB in my Windows 7 64 bit?](https://superuser.com/questions/35731/how-to-enable-4gb-in-my-windows-7-64-bit)

I use Windows 7 64-bit with 4 GB memory installed, but I see only 3.79 GB available. Why is this?

And is it normal to see 1.9 GB memory in use in Task Manager when only the antivirus is running?

Comment: your seeing 3.79gb in Control Panel > All Control Panel items > System ?  if so id venture to say your sharing the 215mb ram with the video. I've also seen ram with bad blocks do this as well, but you'd know with the occasional freeze or shut down.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that Windows uses some of the ram for vital system tasks, and that space decreases the amount of *available* ram. You still have 4gb of ram, just not all of it is available for you to use.

It is pretty common for windows to suck up about half your ram when running idle. This is normal and expected. Although your anti-virus might be scanning in the background and using ram.